# Simple C++ demo for caffe?

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe

I want to implement a simple C++ demo. Its purpose is in loading an image and predicting its class using caffe network.
There is examples/classification/classification.cpp. This example takes exactly 5 arguments:

```
deploy.prototxt network.caffemodel mean.binaryproto labels.txt img.jpg
```

But after training lenet as example, I have only

```
lenet.prototxt and lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel
```

Where should I get mean.binaryproto labels.txt?

Comment: Now I understood the meaning of labels.txt. The question is: how to get mean.binaryproto?

Comment: You don't have to provide mean.binaryprototxt if you didn't substract your training data by it's mean. If I remember right, you just need to normalize your input data from [0,255] to [0,1] for lenet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run that particular network, you can download the required file using `./data/ilsvrc12/get_ilsvrc_aux.sh`

If you have a dataset you can generate the mean file using compute_image_mean executable located at `./build/tools`